# C++: Boost Library and DFS in a R-Tree

Tags: c++, boost, tree, boost-geometry, spatial-query

I've got some 2d points inserted in a R-Tree with Boost Library. The problem is that I don't know how to do a Depth First Search (DFS) from the top node to the leaf. What I want to achieve with this is to calculate the Skyline of the points with Branch and Bound for Skylines (BBS) algorithm. What is more functions like contains, overlaps and covers do not seem to work and don't even compile. Only the "intersects" function works. Below is the code:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>

#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

// to store queries results
#include <vector>

// just for output
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;


int main() {
    typedef bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point;
    typedef bg::model::box<point> box;
    typedef std::pair<point, unsigned> value;
    // create the rtree using default constructor

    bgi::rtree< value, bgi::quadratic<16> > rtree;
    // create some values

    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(1, 12), 1));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(2, 7), 2));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(4, 22), 3));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(5, 14), 4));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(6, 5), 5));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(8, 19), 6));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(9, 9), 7));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(10, 4), 8));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(12, 13), 9));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(15, 22), 10));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(16, 6), 11));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(17, 10), 12));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(17, 20), 13));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(21, 3), 14));
    rtree.insert(std::make_pair(point(22, 14), 15));


    // find values intersecting some area defined by a box
    box query_box(point(5, 4), point(17, 12));
    std::vector<value> result_s;


    bgi::query(rtree, bgi::intersects(query_box), std::back_inserter(result_s));


    // display results
    std::cout << "spatial query box:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << bg::wkt<box>(query_box) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "spatial query result:" << std::endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(value const& v, result_s)
        std::cout << bg::wkt<point>(v.first) << " - " << v.second << std::endl;

    getchar();
}
```

The code seems to work, but how can I do a DFS, or if this cannot be done calculate the Skyline in another way?

Comment: How would you get a skyline from singular points? Are they implied rectangles? How?

Comment: The skyline query problem is about points. You find the points that dominate all other. The R-Tree just creates the bounding boxes so that you can make efficient spatial searching.